# How to automatically create buttons when I upload image?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, image-uploading, inventory-management

I want to know how to automatically create buttons when I upload image using Java (using Netbeans). I am coding inventory management system. I want to implement that part for product ad part.

- Product name,
- product price,
- Bar-code,
- Upload Image of product etc...

After the upload image and update database, that image need to go to sell interface as a clickable button.

Then seller can simply click that image (button) and add to selling list.

What are methods to do that simply?

Hope it is clear what I want.

Comment: with `new JButton(img)` combined with adding i to a panel

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ps.executeQuery(insertSql)>=1)
{
  BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File(ImagePathYouJustInsertedIntoDB));
  button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
  sellingListPanel.add(button);
}
```

after you have inserted the path of your image to the database, now you can simply create an image using the file path that you inserted to the DB, then you create a button, and you add that button to a panel so that the user can see it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give additional sample code to understand more about that?